# Opencart upgrade error

Tags: opencart

i was trying to make an ecommerce site and after i installed opencart, and then the theme i wanted for the site, opencart asked me to upgrade, so this seems like an opencart update to 2.3.0.2 error because that was the version i installed. And after i pressed continue i get the 1091 error. Does anyone know?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiTTA.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYKOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are mentioning in the screenshots is that you already have some mysql tables and the upgrade cannot delete them and create them again.
I would suggest you to do a clean install of 2.3.0.2 or even better, go to version: 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to check database tables and recheck primary keys